# Social Media icons in navbar horizontal spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a personal portfolio and I have a navbar with title, social media icons and navigation links.  When viewing on mobile, the social media icons appear vertically under the title.  I would like them to show up horizontally next to the title, so in between the title and the icon bar.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand text-center" href="index.html">Title Website</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Small social media icons -->
                <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left">
                       <li><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></a></li>
                       <li><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></a></li>
                       <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></a></li>
                </ul>


                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-right" id="navbar-collapse-1">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav text-center">
                            <li><a href="index.html"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="projects.html"><b>Projects</b></a></li>
                            <li><a href="media/resume.pdf" target="_blank"><b>CV/Resume</b></a></li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>

                </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS:

```
/* Navigation */
.navbar-header {
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
}

.navbar-brand {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: baseline !important;
}

.icon-bar {
    background-color: black;
}

nav ul {
    display: inline;
}

nav li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Also, I would like the title to be vertically aligned when viewing on desktop.  I tried `navbar-brand {vertical-align: middle !important}` but that did not work.

Thank you.
-Z

Comment: I tried float: left !important and display: inline and inline-block and neither work.

Comment: Can you add fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vfu9us4g/#&togetherjs=iOgCGDv38p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the icons how I wanted them by playing around. New code:

HTML:

```
        <!-- Small social media icons -->
        <ul class="nav navbar navbar-nav navbar-left pull-left">
            <li id="socmed"><a href="https://twitter.com/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-twitter fa-lg"></a></li>
            <li id="socmed"><a href="https://github.com/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-github fa-lg"></a></li>
            <li id="socmed"><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/" target="_blank" class="fa fa-linkedin fa-lg"></a></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#socmed {
display: inline-block !important;
float: left !important;
}
```